# iOS Beginner: UIWebView does not adjust autom. the resolution of showing webpage (Tumblr Blog)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

when I open my blog (golflounge.tumblr.com) on Safari on iPhone the resolutions gets 
adjusted to fit the small screen. I see the whole pictures, no need to scroll left 
and right.

When I open the the same page on my own app the pictures are way to big and do not fit the screen. I have to scroll to the left and right to see everything.

Any idea whats missing in my app?

Regards,
Marc

P.S There is no re-direction to any mobile address in Safari when I open my blog.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://golflounge.tumblr.com";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
All the tumbl blogs have mobile view - http://golflounge.tumblr.com/mobile
just add the /mobile to the end of URL

Try to use

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

From documentation:

> If YES, the webpage is scaled to fit and the user can zoom in and zoom
>   out. If NO, user zooming is disabled. The default value is NO.

Comment: Must have overlooked the /mobile. Thanks a lot! Works now.

Comment: scalesPageToFit fixed my Tumblr woes! Thanks =)